# I am trying to connect to SQL Server by using the using(){} .. but my Visual Studio shows the following error :

Tags: c#, ado.net

Error

> Invalid token 'using' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace BusinessLayer
{
    class EmployeeBusinessLayer
    {
      String Connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConStr"].ConnectionString;
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection()){
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You have a wide variety of errors in your code.  I recommend you pick up a book or read an online tutorial and acquire the base-level skills necessary to ask real questions on SO.  You should not be using this site to learn about the primitive concepts of a language new to you.

Comment: You're trying to use a `using` statement class-level. Wrap your code in a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to use the `using` statement at the class scope, which is invalid. Try the following:

```
public void YourMethod() {
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConStr"].ConnectionString.ToString();
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection()) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it and help.